# Не работает парсер

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Помогите разобраться в парсере. Хочу скачать заголовки и ссылки с yandex_news, но скрипт вместо того, что-бы вернуть массив таких строк

```
    <a class="b-link" href="/*Много кода...*/" onmousedown="/*Много кода...*/">Заголовок</a>
```

Возвращает мне много левых элементов

```
     $politics = file_get_contents('http://news.yandex.ru/politics.html?lang=ru&nar=0');
     preg_match_all("/\<a class=\"b-link\" href=\"(.*)\" onmousedown=\"(.*)\"\>(.*)\<\/a\>/",$politics,$arr);
```

В чем проблема ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в регулярном выражении, инфа 100%.

```
\<a class=\"b-link\" href=\"[^<>]+\" onmousedown=\"[^<>]+\"\>[^<>]+\<\/a\>
```

Comment: а что делают вот эти символы [^<>], зачем они тут ?

Comment: [^<>] - означает "все символы кроме '<', '>'".